# Nextcord Discord Bot, Use API with Pexels API to get random images

Tags: python, command, slash, nextcord

Just like the title, I'm wanting to use the pexels API in a slash command to get random images from pexels (or any other site) using nextcord bot, hosting on repl.it. See code below:

```
@client.slash_command(name = "init", description = "Get Images for your inits", guild_ids=[testServerId])
async def init(interaction: Interaction):
  await interaction.response.defer()
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession()as session:
    async with session.get(url = "https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated", headers = {'Authorization': "23456789"}, data = {"per_page": "1"}) as response:
      raw = await response.text()
      raw = raw.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
      init = json.loads(raw)
      url = init["url"]
      myobj = {'per_page':'1'}
      embed = nextcord.Embed(page = init["page"], timestamp = datetime.now(), color = nextcord.Colour.green())
      try:
        embed.add_field(name = "Copyright", value = init["copyright"])
      except KeyError:
        pass
      embed.set_image(url = url, myobj = myobj)
      embed.set_footer(text = f"From {init['date']}")
      await interaction.followup.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://github.com/wikicodetutorials/nextcord-pexels-bot/)

[main.py](https://github.com/wikicodetutorials/nextcord-pexels-bot/blob/main/main.py)

If you want to make HTTP Requests in Python regularly, you'd use the requests library for Python. Making a GET request in this library and converting it into a JSON is as simple as

```py
import requests
#...
response = requests.get(api_url)
json = response.json()
```

However, Pexels is unique. Run in your terminal

```bash
pip3 install pexels-api
```

For Replit, install the pexels-api package. 
Make sure you have an API Key from Pexels, which is 100% free. If you don't you can [create one](https://www.pexels.com/api/new/). To set it up in Python:

```py
#...
from pexels-api import API

API_KEY = "PEXEL_API_KEY"
api = API(API_KEY)
```

Now, create a slash command. You can do this by adding somewhere in your code:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="init", description="Command Description") #I chose init because you named the function above init()
async def init(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    # We'll add code here right now
```

You can then get a random curated image by using api.curated(per_page=1)

```py
curatedPhoto = api.curated(per_page=1)
```

Now its as simple as getting our photo and sending it to our user:

```py
photo = curatedPhoto['photos'][0]
await interaction.response.send_message(content=str(photo))
```

Or if you wanted an embed:

```py
photo = curatedPhoto['photos'][0]
embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Photo", description="")
embed.set_thumbnail(str(photo))
await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Hope all of this helped **ツ**